# Sintaxis bucle for anidado en una sola linea

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

Estoy haciendo un curso de tensorflow en Python y para definir una variable utilizan el siguiente código:

```
for x in y.split('\t') if len(x)

birth_data = [[float(x) for x in y.split('\t') if len(x)>=1] for y in birth_data[1:]if len(y)>=1]
birth_data
```

Antes se han importado los datos desde una url y se han almacenado en la variable `birth_data` mediante `split` de texto.

Luego se ha extraído el `header` y ahora se haría el código que he puesto.

Entiendo que el código que adjunto es una forma más avanzada de poner lo que pondría un novato como yo en 5 o 6 líneas, pero no logro comprender que hace el y `split()` ni como se traduciría en lenguaje novato el `if` al lado del `for`.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

En general una comprensión de listas tiene la sintaxis:

```
r = [ expresion for variable in iterable if expresion_booleana ]
```

y básicamente equivale a:

```
r = []
for variable in iterable:
  if expresion_booleana:
    r.append(expresion)
```

Como ves el `if` que se usa en las comprensiones de listas hace de "filtro" para decidir qué elementos se agregarán a la lista resultante (sólo los que pasen la condición del `if`, descartando los que no).

La comprensión de listas que indicas en la pregunta es algo más compleja, porque la `expresion` que se está añadiendo la lista resultado, es a su vez otra comprensión de listas, lo que equivale a tener dos bucles anidados.

Esto:

```
birth_data = [[float(x) for x in y.split('\t') if len(x)>=1] for y in birth_data[1:]if len(y)>=1]
```

equivale al siguiente par de bucles anidados:

```
resultado = []  # Inicializar con lista vacía
for y in birth_data[1:]:
  if len(y) >=1:
     lista_auxiliar = []  # La lista que vamos a agregar a resultado
     for x in y.split("\t"):
        if len(x) >= 1:
           lista_auxilar.append(float(x))
     # Una vez construida la lista auxiliar, se agrega
     resultado.append(lista_auxiliar)

birth_data = resultado   # Reemplazar la lista original por la que resulta del procesado
```

El `split("\t")` opera sobre la variable `y`, que se entiende que es una cadena, dividiendo esa cadena en trozos, usando el caracter tabulador (`\t`) como separador. El resultado es otro iterable, en el que cada iteración se obtendría uno de esos trozos, que en este caso va a parar a la variable `x` y si la longitud del trozo es mayor o igual a 1 se convierte a `float` para añadirlo a la lista auxiliar. La lista auxiliar resultante (con todos los `x` ya convertidos en floats) se añade a su vez a la lista `resultado`.